# WMI Warranty information

Tags: powershell, wmi, sccm

I have a Powershell script(1) that collects the Warranty information for a Dell system and will display it to the screen. I also have a second script(2) that creates a WMI Namespace and (3)one for a class. What I am trying to do it to get the information gathered by the warranty script to end up in the WMI class so we can pull it through SCCM. The code below is what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
(1)

```
{
    $service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://{143.166.84.118}/services/assetservice.asmx?WSDL

    if($args.count -ne 0){
        $serial = $args[0]
    }
    else {
        $system = Get-WmiObject win32_SystemEnclosure
        $serial = $system.serialnumber
    }
    $guid = [guid]::NewGuid()
    $info = $service.GetAssetInformation($guid,'check_warranty.ps1',$serial)
    if($info.count -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host "Machine is not a Dell"
    }
    else
    {
        $warranty = $info[0].Entitlements[0]
        $expires = $warranty.EndDate
        $days_left = $warranty.DaysLeft
        if($days_left -eq 0)
        {
            Write-Host "Warranty has expired"
        }
        else{
            `enter code here`
            set objwmiservice = getobject("winmgts:\\computer\root\warranty")
            set colitems = objwmiservice.execquery("select * from warranty_warranty")

            objitem.Warranty = $expires
            objitem.put_
            next

            Write-Host "Warranty expires $expires."
            Write-Host "Warranty is valid for $days_left days."
        }
    }
}
```

(2)

```
'Create namespace 
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root")

Set objItem = objWMIService.Get("__Namespace")
Set objNamespace = objItem.SpawnInstance_

objNamespace.Name = "Warranty"
objNamespace.Put_ '
```

(3)

```
' $newClass = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass `
    ("root\Warranty", [String]::Empty, $null); 

$newClass["__CLASS"] = "Warranty"; 

$newClass.Qualifiers.Add("Static", $true)
$newClass.Properties.Add("Warranty", `
    [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
$newClass.Properties["Warranty"].Qualifiers.Add("Key", $true)


$newClass.Put()'`enter code here`
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: http://exar.ch/collecting-custom-wmi-classes-with-sccm/

Comment: I am trying to use a WMI script to #1 pull the warranty information from dell. #2 Place the information in to a new WMI class.